# Raphael Rect & Text not aligning

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael, jquery-svg

I'm having a strange problem that I'm just baffled by.

I am using Raphael to draw rectangles and text.

I'd like to have my text right next to my rectangles, like a legend.

I know I am drawing the rect and text at the same height, but it's just not showing up that way!

Here is my code so far, and some examples of what I mean:

```
var xPos = ...
var yPos = ...
var squareWidth = ...
var squareHeight = ...
var iconname = ...
var iconvalue = ...

console.log("Drawing color rect for '"+iconname+"' at "+xPos+", "+yPos);
this.colorsLegendPaper.rect(xPos, yPos, squareWidth, squareHeight, 4)
        .attr({stroke:iconvalue, "stroke-width": 4});

//move slightly to the right:
xPos=xPos+squareWidth+5; 
//If I have a rect starting at (0,0) with height 3, 
//text needs to start at (0,1.5) to be aligned.
yPos=yPos+(squareHeight/2); 

console.log("Drawing color text for '"+iconname+"' at "+xPos+", "+yPos);
this.colorsLegendPaper.text(yPos, yPos, iconname)
        .attr({"font-size":12, "text-anchor":"start"});
```

The console output I am getting is this (which is what **I am expecting**):

```
Drawing color rect for 'Test 1' at 5, 1      //These line up great  v
Drawing color text for 'Test 1' at 30, 11
Drawing color rect for 'Test 2' at 150, 1
Drawing color text for 'Test 2' at 175, 11
Drawing color rect for 'Test 3' at 5, 31     //These do not    v
Drawing color text for 'Test 3' at 30, 41
Drawing color rect for 'Test 4' at 150, 31
Drawing color text for 'Test 4' at 175, 41
```

Looks great! But... this is what it really looks like:

[image]

What happened? **Why are the "31" and "41" elements displaying more like "31" and "81"?**

The "1" and "11" elements look great, but when I go down to the next level, something messes up.

Here is the full source of the svg:

```
<svg style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; " height="115" version="1.1" width="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); ">Created with Raphaël 2.1.2</desc>
<defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); "></defs>

<rect style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); " x="5" y="1" width="20" height="20" r="4" rx="4" ry="4" fill="none" stroke="#4db85f" stroke-width="4"></rect>
<text style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: start; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial; " x="30" y="11" text-anchor="start" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="none" fill="#000000" font-size="12px">
<tspan style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); " dy="11">Test 1</tspan></text>

<rect style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); " x="150" y="1" width="20" height="20" r="4" rx="4" ry="4" fill="none" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="4"></rect>
<text style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: start; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial; " x="175" y="11" text-anchor="start" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="none" fill="#000000" font-size="12px">
<tspan style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); " dy="11">Test 2</tspan></text>

<rect style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); " x="5" y="31" width="20" height="20" r="4" rx="4" ry="4" fill="none" stroke="#ffff00" stroke-width="4"></rect>
<text style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: start; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial; " x="30" y="41" text-anchor="start" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="none" fill="#000000" font-size="12px">
<tspan style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); " dy="41">Test 3</tspan></text>

<rect style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); " x="150" y="31" width="20" height="20" r="4" rx="4" ry="4" fill="none" stroke="#0000ff" stroke-width="4"></rect>
<text style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: start; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial; " x="175" y="41" text-anchor="start" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="none" fill="#000000" font-size="12px">
<tspan style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); " dy="41">Test 4</tspan></text></svg>
```

This happens on all my pages :(

It gets worse if I have multiple "papers" on the page

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Here's a thought: maybe I could try using textpath's

Comment: There's something pertinent you haven't included in your samples. The `dy` attribute of `tspan`, according the the [Raphaël documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform), indicates some sort of translation or transformation of the element is occuring in the Y-axis, which explains the discrepancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was doing **$("#myDiv").hide()**, and at the time of drawing the text, the div was not "connected" to the DOM, so Raphael couldn't get the height of the element. Or, from [@qbolec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19953023/1696153) :

> I had similar issue, when using raphael + Backbone. I found this issue
>   on git hub illuminating. The rootcause in my case is that I am
>   operating on a view which is not attached to DOM at the moment I use
>   Paper.text. As explained in the issue, this causes Raphael to believe
>   that the bounding box has no height. Combined with answer of Matt
>   Esch, this results in adjusting dy to be equal to y. As a workaround
>   you could try to attach the element to the DOM for a moment of
>   drawing.

The github article that helped was: https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/491